# OnClick listener for button inside compound view

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I created a compound view which consist of three views, two `ImageButtons` and one EditText. I am trying to create new "`MyView`" view everytime button is clicked. Firstly I decided to set onClick in xml hoping that everytime a new MyView is created, it will have listener set already but it does not seem to work. So my question is, how to set onClick listener, for a button inside compound view, and method is in other class? Method I am talking about is addViewBelow() in `ViewControl` vlass

```
MyView.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_weight="80" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:onClick="addViewBelow"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/add" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/rmv"
    android:background="@drawable/rmv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyView.java

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

private EditText txt;
private ImageView add, rmv;

public MyView(Context context)
{
super(context);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, this);

txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
rmv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rmv);

}



public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, this);

txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
rmv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rmv);


}
```

ViewControl.java

```
public class ViewControl implements OnClickListener {

    LinkedList<MyView> pathView;
    Button mainButton;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    Activity act;
    int lastId;

public ViewControl(Activity activity) {

act = activity;
//stuff

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//stuff

    }

public void addViewBelow() {

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);

MyView mv = new MyView(act);

mv.setId(UniqueID.generateViewId());
mv.setLayoutParams(params);
lastId = mv.getId();
pathView.add(mv);
rl.addView(pathView.getLast());
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `android:onClick` to work, the method must be in the View`s context, which most often is an Activity.

For your case, I'd suggest the following:

Add this method to MyView:

```
public void setClickListener(OnClickListener listener){
    add.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

in `addViewBelow`, do this:

```
mv.setClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        addViewBelow();    
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I thought of something like this before but was not sure if it is good idea so I just skipped it. I will accept this ASAP :)
EDIT: And it is great you mentioned that XML part where method must be only in View's context, no more wasting time for trying to do something that is not possible.